# TestNG onConfigurationFailure: How do I then register all tests and set as failed?

Tags: testng

I'm having with testng and how our test system reports failures. Put simply, I want to register and mark all tests as FAILED if I hit an issue in the before class.

I've tried hacking it together using our system, but I'm hoping there is an internal way of doing this. I have the following test:

```
@BeforeClass
void beforeClass()
{
  log.debug("Before class")
  AssertUtils.assertIs(false, true)
}

@Test
void testA()
{
  log.debug("I'm a test :-) ")
}
```

Now, the test is skipped as we hit an exception in the before class. We overide onConfigurationFailure and note this. Sadly, testA never gets registered, so I have 0 passed, 0 skipped and 0 failed. Our test system then marks this suite as PASSED due to being 0 failures.

Interestingly, if I call testContext.getSkippedTests() I can see the skipped method, but this isn't being bubbled up. I effectively want to mark that test as an actual FAILURE.

I'm using testng 6.14.3 (tried 7.0.0-beta7 but this requires a code change somewhere I assume) and intelliJ 2019.1.3. Any advice appreciated :-)

Answer (score 1):

I am using the latest released version of TestNG (`7.0.0-beta7` as of today).

Here's a TestNG listener that demonstrates how to do this:

```java
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import org.testng.IReporter;
import org.testng.IResultMap;
import org.testng.ISuite;
import org.testng.ITestContext;
import org.testng.ITestListener;
import org.testng.ITestNGMethod;
import org.testng.ITestResult;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite;

public class SkipDetector implements ITestListener, IReporter {
  private final Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> failures = new HashMap<>();
  private final Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> skips = new HashMap<>();

  Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> getFailures() {
    return failures;
  }

  Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> getSkips() {
    return skips;
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
    IResultMap skippedTestMap = context.getSkippedTests();
    Set<ITestResult> toBeMarkedAsFailed = new HashSet<>();
    for (ITestResult result : skippedTestMap.getAllResults()) {
      List<ITestNGMethod> skipCause = result.getSkipCausedBy();
      if (skipCause.isEmpty()) {
        continue;
      }
      boolean causedByConfigFailure =
          skipCause.stream().anyMatch(iTestNGMethod -> !iTestNGMethod.isTest());
      if (causedByConfigFailure) {
        toBeMarkedAsFailed.add(result);
      }
    }
    IResultMap failedTestMap = context.getFailedTests();
    toBeMarkedAsFailed.forEach(
        iTestResult -> failedTestMap.addResult(iTestResult, iTestResult.getMethod()));
    toBeMarkedAsFailed.forEach(skippedTestMap::removeResult);
  }

  @Override
  public void generateReport(
      List<XmlSuite> xmlSuites, List<ISuite> suites, String outputDirectory) {
    suites.stream()
        .flatMap(iSuite -> iSuite.getResults().values().stream())
        .collect(Collectors.toList())
        .forEach(
            result -> {
              String suiteName = result.getTestContext().getSuite().getName();
              String testName = result.getTestContext().getName();
              ITestContext ctx = result.getTestContext();
              compute(failures, suiteName, testName, ctx.getFailedTests().size());
              compute(skips, suiteName, testName, ctx.getSkippedTests().size());
            });
  }

  private static void compute(
      Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> outerMap, String suiteName, String testName, int value) {
    Map<String, Integer> innerMap = outerMap.computeIfAbsent(suiteName, s -> new HashMap<>());
    innerMap.putIfAbsent(testName, value);
    outerMap.put(suiteName, innerMap);
  }
}
```

Here's a demo test class which uses the above listener

```java
import java.lang.reflect.Method;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeMethod;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class SampleTestClass {

  @BeforeMethod
  public void beforeMethod(Method method) {
    Test test = method.getAnnotation(Test.class);
    if (test.description().equalsIgnoreCase("failme")) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Simulating configuration failure");
    }
  }

  @Test(description = "failMe")
  public void test1() {}

  @Test
  public void test2() {
    throw new RuntimeException("Simulating a failure");
  }

  @Test(dependsOnMethods = "test2")
  public void test3() {}
}
```

Here's a test runner that uses the above demo class and the listener and asserts the expectations (mark tests which were skipped due to config failures as failed tests)

```java
import java.util.Map;
import org.assertj.core.api.Assertions;
import org.testng.TestNG;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import org.testng.xml.XmlSuite.FailurePolicy;

public class LocalTestRunner {

  @Test
  public void testMethod() {
    TestNG testng = new TestNG();
    testng.setTestClasses(new Class[] {SampleTestClass.class});
    SkipDetector detector = new SkipDetector();
    testng.addListener(detector);
    testng.setVerbose(2);
    testng.setConfigFailurePolicy(FailurePolicy.CONTINUE);
    testng.run();
    for (Map<String, Integer> eachOuter : detector.getSkips().values()) {
      Assertions.assertThat(eachOuter.values()).containsExactly(0);
    }
    for (Map<String, Integer> eachOuter : detector.getFailures().values()) {
      // We have 3 because, test3() has 2 reasons for being skipped.
      // its upstream method viz., test2() failed
      // its beforeMethod configuration never ran at all. So it can be considered as a failure
      // TestNG just picks up the first reason, which in this case is the configuration failure
      // And so its status also gets flipped to failed, even though it was skipped.
      Assertions.assertThat(eachOuter.values()).containsExactly(3);
    }
  }
}
```